# Tornado concurrent vs asynchronous request

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, tornado, concurrent.futures

Supposed that my web server has a load of about 100 req/sec. and I have 70% of the requests that are I/O bound and make a light task (like db queries), while a 30% are cpu bound that make a heavy task (like hashing, calculations, with resources on the file system). The latter requests also are I/O blocking, therefore I'm using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to avoid they will block the faster requests:

```
@tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor
def post(self, *args):
    # I'm a io blocking request
    data = heavy_load_task()
    self.write(data)
```

while the 70% of the requests are implemented with the `asynchronous` decorator, thus requesting a specific call to `self.finish()` in order to explicitly close the socket:

```
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self, *args):
    # I'm a light request
    data = light_load_task()
    self.write(data)
    self.finish()
```

See [here](https://infinitescript.com/2017/06/making-requests-non-blocking-in-tornado/) about making non blocking requests in Tornado.
Specifically rather that using the default thread pool executor like:

```
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(5)
```

I'm using a (hopefully) better implementation that takes care of limit the number of concurrent threads to avoid memory pressure:

```
executor = BoundedThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
```

Please see [this](https://github.com/loretoparisi/python-threading) package for the implementation of the `BoundedThreadPoolExecutor`.

This seems to work ok. For performance reasons, I have tried to move the former light tasks requests from the `@tornado.web.asynchronous` pattern to the `@tornado.concurrent.run_on_executor` pattern, and here I have got a problem. At some point the server stopped serving requests, no crash, no runtime error. It just stopped getting requests and serving the responses with any error or OOM issue on the machine. I have tried different sizes of the `max_workers` workers queue from 5 to 100 concurrent workers with no apparent effect.

Comment: I'm not sure if `ThreadPoolExecutor` will provide the desired performance since for CPU bound workloads the threads are still constrained by the GIL.  Additionally, since they are threads they carry the overhead of concurrency errors (deadlocks) which i'm sort of kind of might think is happening but not at all sure :p.  To achieve parallel CPU execution it looks like there might be a process pool executor: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor .  Is it easy to reach the state where tornado stops processing? If so, could you profile?

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that the wrapper `ProcessPoolExecutor` could be better for parallel executions inside an handler. I have the `BoundedProcessPoolExecutor` custom implementation here https://github.com/loretoparisi/python-threading